# Possible to pass variable to add_filter in Wordpress excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Trying to get this to work, is it even possible to pass a variable like this?

```
function excerpt_read_more($output, $text) {
    global $post;
    return $output . '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="readmore">'.$text.'</a>';
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'excerpt_read_more');
```

I'm trying to be able to do something like this

```
<?php the_excerpt('Read More...'); ?>
```

Since I will want it to say different things throughout the site. For instance, read this post, continue reading the post, view this recipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter [**`the_excerpt`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L248) only has one argument, so what you're trying is not possible.

One option is using a global variable:

```
function excerpt_read_more( $output ) {
    global $post, $my_read_more;
    return $output 
        . '<a href="'
        . get_permalink( $post->ID ) 
        . '" class="readmore">' 
        . $my_read_more 
        . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'excerpt_read_more' );
```

And then, call the function like:

```
<?php
global $my_read_more;
$my_read_more='read this post'; 
the_excerpt();
?>

<?php
global $my_read_more;
$my_read_more='view this recipe'; 
the_excerpt();
?>
```

---

Another solution would be using a Custom Field: [***How to customize read more link***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/56048/12615).

And for usability create a Meta Box with all your "read more" options, so this is defined on post publishing: [***Add a checkbox to post screen that adds a class to the title***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/61041/12615).

Comment: Thanks! This works great, didn't think of passing it as a global. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Also, you don't need to pass the global when calling the function, since it is defined in excerpt_read_more already.